# Python Package Artifactory Pull Replication Problem: Artifactory pulling from Azure Artefacts is not working

Tags: python, artifactory, azure-artifacts

I want to setup a replication on an Artifactory Python repository that pulls Python packages from an Azure Artefacts Python repository.

When I set up the replication and test it I get following error message:
Connection failed: Target replication URL returned error 405: Method Not Allowed

Is this a problem of the configuration or Azure Artefacts or Artifactory?

Comment: According to Artifactory support replication only works between Artifactory instances and not between Artifactory and something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Artifactory support replication only works between Artifactory instances and not between Artifactory and something else.